# Open syncthing port on raspberry pi

Tags: networking, iptables, http

I have just set up a raspberry pi with the raspbian OS. Other than installing LAMP and syncthing, I have not made many changes from the initial setup.

I am accessing my raspi through SSH on LAN, and would like to view the Syncthing GUI through web browsers on devices on the LAN.

The Syncthing GUI runs on port 8384.

I have verified that syncthing runs properly and that I can access it through the browser locally.

In order to enable acces to the port on the LAN, I configured iptables with the following line:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8384 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

However, I still get "err: connection refused" when I try to access the syncthing GUI from other devices on the network by typing the machine's ip address followed by the port number like so: 192.168.1.24:8384

192.168.1.24:80 serves the LAMP welcome page without a hitch.

What steps am I missing?

There are some similar questions and answers on this forum, but none resolve my specific situation.

I am most likely missing some basic step, since I have not worked much with iptables before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syncthing process must listen for connections at all available local IP-addresses, not just at the loopback address.

The [config file](http://docs.syncthing.net/users/config.html) should have a line like

```
<gui enabled="true" tls="false">
    <address>0.0.0.0:8384</address>
```

not

```
<gui enabled="true" tls="false">
    <address>127.0.0.1:8384</address>
```

The documentation explains this:

> **address**
>   Set the listen addresses. One or more address elements must be present. Allowed address formats are:
>
> **IPv4 address and port (127.0.0.1:8384)**
>   The address and port is used as given.
>
> **IPv6 address and port ([::1]:8384)**
>   The address and port is used as given. The address must be enclosed in square brackets.
>
> **Wildcard and port (0.0.0.0:12345, [::]:12345, :12345)**
>   These are equivalent and will result in Syncthing listening on all interfaces and both IPv4 and IPv6.

Note the mention of *all interfaces*.

The loopback address 127.0.0.1 **excludes** connection requests arriving at any other real/physical/virtual network interface card. The purpose of the loopback address is specifically to only permit connections from the same computer.

Comment: Thank you this was the problem. I set it to 0.0.0.0:8384 and it worked. But this opens it up to connections form the world as well. I will be accessing it from the net later, but would like to know if it's possible to limit it to local connections. I tried 192.168.0.0:8384 and 192.168.1.0:8384 but it did not work. Is there a way to only allow lan IPs?

Comment: @Pjottur: Try 192.168.1.24:8384. I assume your iptables configuration is on the same computer and would(or could) take care of security.

Comment: Yes, of course. So when I set the iptables to only allow LAN addresses on the port, I am fine. Good, syncthing gave me a warning that the world could access the GUI, but it is probably not reading the iptables.